# How to predict probabilities from a new data set from an already built and validated model in Python?

Tags: python, logistic, random-forest, modeling

I have built a classification model using the following steps (and in the mentioned order) in Python -

1. Data cleaning - Removing unwanted variables and separating Predictor variables from response variable
2. Label Encoding
3. Standardization( StandardScaler)
4. Train Test Split
5. Smote
6. Model Building
7. Model Testing using Test data

1. Now I have a new dataset, and I want to predict using the above built model. How do I do it ? Which of the above steps should I follow and which ones should I skip ?
2. Also, is the arrangement of any of the steps aforementioned very, very wrong so that it needs to be changed ?

Comment: You did not add any code to your question. It is unclear how you performed all these steps. Which means it is very hard to determine whether you need to do them again or not.

Comment: Train test split should be done before scaling (or any other operation based on info in the data)

Comment: Everything you've  listed is part of your model.  You do all the steps (except splitting and model testing).